# 1.7 function of K&D book . How it calculate 2^0 when p is declared as 1

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int power(int m,int n);
main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d %d %d\n",i,power(2,i),power(-3,i));
    return 0;

}
int power(int base,int n)
{
    int i,p;
    p=1;  // doubt in this line
    for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
        p=p*base;
    return p;

}
```

when p is declared as 1 . Then how it calculate the value for 2^0.yet I'm the beginner of c programming i can't able to get the logic behind this.And my doubt in this function program is  how it works for 2^0 when p=1.Thanks for your replay..

Comment: `2^0` is `1`, so `p = 1` sets the correct answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming by 2^0 you mean the inputs to the function `power` are 2 and 0.

In that case, `n = 0`, and the for loop doesn't even run because `i = 1` which is greater than 0. In that case, the function returns 1 because you initialized `p` to 1, and the loop didn't modify it.

Answer (score 0):

A correct function declaration should look like

```
int power(int base, unsigned int n );
                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise you have to check within the function whether `n` is negative.

As for your question then according to the mathematics `x ^ 0` is equal to `1`.

Within the function `p` is initialized by `1`

```
p=1;  // doubt in this line
```

If `n` is equal to `0` then this loop

```
for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
    p=p*base;
```

will not be executed because its initial condition is evaluated to false

```
i<=n
```

when `i` is initialized by `1` and `n` is equal to `0`.

So the function will return `p` equal to `1`.

```
return p;
```

Otherwise if `n` is greater than `0` at least one iteration of the loop will be executed. It means that this statement

```
    p = p*base;
```

will be executed the number of times equal to `n` and `p` will store `base ^ n`

As for me I would write the function the following way

```
long long int power( int base, unsigned int n )
{
    long long int p = 1;

    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; ++i ) p *= base;

    return p;
}
```